# AVAudioSession .playAndRecord low volume issue with AirPods

Tags: ios, bluetooth, avfoundation, avaudiosession

I have a ViewController that records a users audio and then plays it back. I am using the .playAndRecord category of the AVAudioSession to handle the recording and playback. I have the options

```
[.allowBluetooth, .defaultToSpeaker, .allowBluetoothA2DP]
```

One issue I'm having is the recording volume of the AirPods vs the device mic. The device mic is noticeably louder on playback. This causes an  issue when combining users who used the device mic vs AirPod users.

I know the sample rate is different for AirPods vs device mic.

Is there anything I can do to alleviate this problem? I've confirmed that a podcast recording software (Anchor) records with both device mic and Airpod mic without a noticeable difference, so I believe there is a solution, I just don't know what direction to go.